# start class in new thread

Tags: android, multithreading, email

(API level 12)
I have implemented the javax.mail to be able to send Emails after the user enter the login name and password. For some reason I was able to run it one time and email went of. Now I get an error NetworkOnMainThreadException. I look around and I see that you can start a new thread like this:

```
  Thread onRun = new Thread{
      public void run() {
           try{
               mail.send();
           }catch(Exception e) {
           }
      }
   };
   onRun.Start();
```

But the application crash when i add it.

Is there a way to always have the class running in a new thread so I never get the error?
Thanks for any help.

```
public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator { 
private String _user; 
private String _pass; 

private String[] _to; 
private String _from; 

private String _port; 
private String _sport; 

private String _host; 

private String _subject; 
private String _body; 

private boolean _auth; 

private boolean _debuggable; 

private Multipart _multipart; 


public Mail() { 
_host = ""; // default smtp server 
_port = ""; // default smtp port 
_sport = ""; // default socketfactory port 

_user = ""; // username 
_pass = ""; // password 
_from = ""; // email sent from 
_subject = ""; // email subject 
_body = ""; // email body 

_debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off 
_auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on 

_multipart = new MimeMultipart(); 

// There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added. 
MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap(); 
mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html"); 
mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml"); 
mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain"); 
mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed"); 
mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822"); 
CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc); 
} 

public Mail(String user, String pass) { 
 this(); 

_user = user; 
_pass = pass; 
} 

public boolean send() throws Exception { 
   Properties props = _setProperties(); 

if(!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0 && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("") && !_body.equals("")) { 
  Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this); 

  MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session); 

  msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from)); 

  InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length]; 
  for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) { 
    addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]); 
  } 
    msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo); 

  msg.setSubject(_subject); 
  msg.setSentDate(new Date()); 

  // setup message body 
  BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
  messageBodyPart.setText(_body); 
  _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 

  // Put parts in message 
  msg.setContent(_multipart); 

  // send email 
  Transport.send(msg); 

  return true; 
} else { 
  return false; 
} 
} 

public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception { 
BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename); 
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source)); 
messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename); 

_multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 
} 

@Override 
public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() { 
   return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass); 
} 

private Properties _setProperties() { 
Properties props = new Properties(); 

props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host); 

if(_debuggable) { 
  props.put("mail.debug", "true"); 
} 

if(_auth) { 
  props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false"); 
} 

props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port); 
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport); 
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"); 
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false"); 

return props; 
} 

// the getters and setters 
public String getBody() { 
return _body; 
} 

public void setBody(String _body) { 
this._body = _body; 
} 

public void setTo(String[] toArr) {
  this._to = toArr;
  }

public void setFrom(String string) {
  this._from = string;
  }

public void setSubject(String string) {
  this._subject = string;
  } 

public void setSMTP(String string) {
  this._host = string;
  }

public void setPort(String string) {
  this._port = string;
  } 
public void setSPort(String string) {
  this._sport = string;
  } 

}
```

Comment: Have you tried `AsyncTask` as your Thread?

Answer (score 1):

As the name of the exception — [`NetworkOnMainThreadException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) — you can't interact with the network on main thread. Consider using [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). There are some sample codes inside SDK folder.

Comment: I don't see how I can add AsyncTask to my class I already have a extends and I need to use extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) { and what would I put instead of URL? Can I start the thread when I call the Send() instead?

Comment: All parameters for `AsyncTask` are arbitrary, hence you can use anything you want. If you have time, please see documentation of [`NetworkOnMainThreadException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html).

Comment: I looked a the link and it just tells me what kind of exception it is. How would I use AsyncTask on the above class?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. You can use Google, I think there are some examples on the internet. Or you might want to have a look at SDK folder, there are some samples code…